# django default profile image

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to setup a default profile image URL using an image on my static files.
When I have a profile image using this works fine

```
<img src="{% if user.avatar %}{{ user.avatar.url }}{% endif %}">
```

and when I try the default image

```
<img  src="{% static 'img/default-avatar.png' %}">
```

works fine as well

but when I clear the image trying to show the default image I get

## ValueError at : The 'avatar' attribute has no file associated with it.

```
#my model
class User(AbstractUser):
    #otherstuff 
    avatar         = models.ImageField(null=True ,blank=True)
    #morestuff 

#template 

    <img src="{% if user.avatar %}{{ user.avatar.url }}{% else %}{% static 'img/default-avatar.png' %} {% endif %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django there is a simple way to do this :

```
<img src="{{ user.avatar.url|default:"img/default-avatar.png" }}">
```

Don't forget to load statics files on the top of your template :

```
{% load static %}
```

Comment: same error tried hard coding the url using default and default_if_none

Comment: Why do you use user.avatar.url and not just user.avatar ? Could you post your entire view ?

Comment: using user avatar would give me the user image file name whie using url will give me the link of the image in the media folder where its been uploaded